# How to redirect user to dashboard.html page after facebook login

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth, facebook-login

I tried to implement login using facebook and i want after logging in user directly redirected to dashboard.html page that i'm unable to do please help me.

below is the code for OAuthConfiguration

**OAuth2Configuration.java**

```
package com.org.config;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Configuration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

}
```

below is the code for MainController from index.html page /api will triggered and getUser method will run from here we are getting prinicipal user details
**MainController.java**

```
package com.org.controller;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.security.Principal;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping
    public Principal getUser(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

below is the code for index.html page contains one link for login with facebook and that im hiding it after successfull login
**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <base href="/"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Demo</h1>

<div class="container unauthenticated">
    Login With Facebook: <a href="/login">click here</a>
</div>
<div class="container authenticated" style="display:none">
    Logged into Facebook as: <span id="user"></span>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get("/api", function(data) {
        $("#user").html(data.userAuthentication.details.name);
        $(".unauthenticated").hide()
        $(".authenticated").show()
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**below is the code for application.yml file**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: 2180810022116587
      clientSecret: 3ded0043a2b8300f0a8af44bbb531026
      accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

**[Link for latest code](https://github.com/daadestroyer/meta-login-spring)**